# primeng 14 scrollpanel with dropdown, when dropdown expanded whole content shifts left

Tags: angular, dropdown, primeng

I am using primeng14 scroll panel and p-dropdown, when dropdown is selected it shift and hides the content to the left.
after clicking

[image: click to view]

before clicking
[image: click to view]

stackblitz url to reproduce https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-scrollpanel-demo-fghtiv?file=src/app/app.component.scss

I tried using appendTo=body to the dropdown it worked but I want a solution without appendTo attribute it happening with the pagination dropdown as well.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I am experiencing the same

Comment: @DusanRadovanovic Im have used appendTo attribute to fix it